# How to treat the first line of the data file as column labels in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a table like this:

```
A B C D E F G H I 
10 23998 16755 27656 17659 19708 20328 19377 18925
20 37298 33368 53936 41421 44548 40756 40985 37294
```

I use this command to plot

```
plot "C:/file.txt" using 1:2 with lines smooth bezier, "C:/file.txt" using 1:3 with lines smooth bezier, ...
```

However, all the labels come out as the file name. Is it possible for gnuplot to read the first row and label the lines accordingly?

Comment: I suppose this is a cmd.exe command line parsing issue rather than a gnuplot issue. Can you line out the desired command line syntax for those who have no knowledge of gnuplot?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure what you mean. All this happens purely in gnuplot.

Comment: @Tomalak: this is done in the gnuplot shell, it has nothing to do with cmd.exe command-line parsing. (The same thing happens on Linux)

Comment: For those that want to name axis labels in a scatter plot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089301/how-do-i-set-axis-label-with-column-header-in-gnuplot

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
set key autotitle columnhead
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if the header starts with a hash?

Answer (score 4):

```
plot for [n=2:12] 'vv.csv' u 1:(column(n)) w lines title columnhead(n)
```

`n` starts from 2 to skip the header.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the documentation and I don't see a way to do it automatically, but you can manually set a title with

```
plot "file.txt" using 1:2 title "A" with lines smooth bezier ...
```

Comment: if the data format is ecactly the way you described in your question I would use this manual aproach as well

Answer (score -1):

I once [wrote](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/2007-05/msg00075.html) a script to plot FM radio station frequencies along an axis from 87MHz to 108MHz, using the names of each radio station as vertical labels. This was not a pure gnuplot solution, the input file is processed with perl with make, but I suggest you have a look at it and see if you can use something like that.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a gnuplot toolkit such as [this one for Python](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) if you want have a lot of data to plot and you want to automate the extraction of the titles.