# How do I set axis label with column header in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, columnheader

My question is very simple. Suppose I have a datafile with column headers, like as follows

```
first second
1 1 
2 1
3 6
4 9
```

In gnuplot how do i make it so that the datafile is plotted using the column header as axis label? e.g. by calling

```
plot datafile using 1:2
```

i get the xaxis labeled `first` and the yaxis labeled `second`?

edit: I do know that I can use the column header as a key entry via `set key auto title column head`, however that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate the suggestion of @andyras, here is how you can do it:

```
datafile = 'filename.txt'
firstrow = system('head -1 '.datafile)
set xlabel word(firstrow, 1)
set ylabel word(firstrow, 2)
plot datafile using 1:2
```

You must plot with the explicit `using` statement, otherwise gnuplot will complain about `bad data on line 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this feature is built in to gnuplot; you would probably have to use an awk-like utility to pull those labels out of a datafile.

You could try submitting a feature request on gnuplot's sourceforge site, and get feedback from the developers there.

Comment: `awk` + `head -1` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Another question where people believe it can't be done with gnuplot. Here is a simple *gnuplot-only* solution without external tools, hence platform-independent.

**Data:** `SO16089301.dat`

```
first second
1 1 
2 1
3 6
4 9
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### extracting axes labels from datafile
reset

FILE = 'SO16089301.dat'

stats FILE u (myX=strcol(1), myY=strcol(2)) every ::0::0 nooutput

set xlabel myX
set ylabel myY

plot FILE u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I think it is supported.  You are just supposed to be able to use "":

> plot 'file' using "first":"second"

Although, if you want to do math in your using specification, you'll need the column("") function, too

> plot 'file' using "first":(column("second")-(column("thrid"))

(Using only quoted header names with the math didn't work for me, anyway.)

Comment: With your method you can select the columns by the header strings, instead of using 1 and 2, but these headers aren't used as axis labels.