# Gnuplot set x y labels from column header (from file)

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Considering the data (in file, `test.txt`):

```
i x(volts) y(amp)
0 1 5   
1 2 6   
2 3 7   
3 4 8   
4 5 3   
5 5 4
```

If I do:

```
set key autotitle columnheader
plot "test.txt" using 1:2
```

Then I get:

[image]

And, if I do:

```
set xlabel "x(volts)"
set ylabel "y(amp)"
plot "test.txt" using 1:2
```

Then I get

[image]

In the first case I read the label from file but it went into the legend. In the second case I set the x y labels but not reading from file.

How do I set x y labels reading from file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089301/2604213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `system` command to get output of the external program into variable.

```
s=system('head -n 1 test.txt')
set xlabel word(s,2)
set ylabel word(s,3)
plot 'test.txt' u 1:2
```